# How to get entity object instance in Oracle ADF

Tags: database, oracle-adf

Type of application: ADF Fusion Web

I'm in the java file of Entity `foo` in a method I'm coding within that class. I want to access the instance of the `bar` Entity to get some value and ultimately build a business rule for the `foo` entity

How do I get the entity object instance?

Answer (score 0):

1.You need an association between Entity Foo and Entity Bar.

2.Then, you need to make sure the association exposes the Entity Bar accessors from within Entity Foo.

3.From Entity Foo, you can then:
    this.getEntityBar().callWhatever()

Answer (score -1):

In the method `setidfoo()`

```
setattributeyouwanttoset(this.getbar().gettheattributeyouaregettingtheinfofrom());
```

hope this helps, obvsiouly make sure you are using the same type (number) and it should be working fine